# Decomposition of direct sum representation of a Lie Group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Suppose that $(\varphi,V)$ is an irreducible finite dimensional representation of a Lie group $G$ and let $\psi=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n{\varphi}$ the representation on $W=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n{V}$. I want to show that $Hom_G(V,W)$ is $n$-dimensional and that $End_G(V\oplus V)$ is $4$-dimensional.

For the first part i got the idea that it may be possible to prove that $Hom_G(V,W)\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^nHom_G(V,V)$ and from Schurs Lemma we may conclude that $Hom_G(V,V)$ is one-dimensional, thus the sum is n-dimensional. But i don't know how to write this down on a good way. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: What you wrote down is perfect. Since finite direct sums are also products, a map from a given representation $V$ into $\oplus_{i=1}^{n} V_{i}$ (where $V_{i}$ are arbitrary) is the same as giving $n$ choices of maps from $V$ to each $V_{i}$.
For the second part, use the fact that maps from $V \oplus V$ to $U$ (for any representation $U$) are pairs of maps from $V$ to $U$, and then apply to the case where $U = V \oplus V.$

Comment: Thank you for answer. What do you mean by finite direct sums are also products?